# rails 5x problem it is possible to add route without crud?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rubygems, crud

Hello for begin is not possible for me to add some things at my route.rb

is juste possible to use resources.

## my route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#home'
  devise_for :users

  resources :faucets
  resources :posts
  resources :users

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  
end
```

I want to link a button for do a modification on my wallet user the principe is add money on the wallet at my user whith a simple button don' forget it is posible to just using resources.

## my tab user

| ID | EMAIL | ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD | RESET_PASSWORD_TOKEN | RESET_PASSWORD_SENT_AT | REMEMBER_CREATED_AT | CREATED_AT | UPDATED_AT | ADMIN | WALLET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | rolf@kassulke-rohan.biz | $2a$12$xpCaMAWCDqDm7QrLR98z... |  |  |  | 2021-03-13 17:32:59 | 2021-03-13 17:32:59 | false | 0 |
| 10 | malcolm@smith.net | $2a$12$SBk4Ok4qtdresgA.V7KP... |  |  |  | 2021-03-13 17:33:00 | 2021-03-13 17:33:00 | false | 0 |
| 11 | raymond@langosh.info | $2a$12$5mRP2WCS98Pa.2DF0dO.... |  |  |  | 2021-03-13 17:33:01 | 2021-03-13 17:33:01 | false | 0 |
| 12 | edwin@padberg.net | $2a$12$hUBW4ZZBUPGN06jOlV37... |  |  |  | 2021-03-13 17:33:02 | 2021-03-13 17:33:02 | false | 0 |
| 13 | setsuko@feeney.info | $2a$12$5hIY76sZyjp3GFgxX.6I... |  |  |  | 2021-03-13 17:33:02 | 2021-03-13 17:33:02 | false | 0 |
| 8 | ai@wiegand.org | $2a$12$XD.3sehDXE0WCVavfWDY... |  |  |  | 2021-03-13 17:32:58 | 2021-03-13 17:36:50 | false | 0 |
| 14 | back-phonix@lie.fr | $2a$12$Iia9pUpGDJPCeuYTUvAk... |  |  |  | 2021-03-13 17:38:10 | 2021-03-13 23:15:25 | true | 1042 |

## my controller

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def faucet
    if current_user.wallet >= 10000
      current_user.update(wallet: 10000)
      flash.alert = "your wallet is full !"
      redirect_to request.referrer
    else
      @dice = rand(1...50)
      x = current_user.wallet + @dice
      current_user.update(wallet: x)
      redirect_to request.referrer
    end

    if current_user.wallet == 0
      flash.alert = "your wallet is empty !"
      redirect_to request.referrer
    end
  end
end
```

## index.html.erb

```
<p class="d-flex justify-content-center p-3">Wallet : <%= current_user.wallet  %></p>

<%= button_to 'faucet', {:controller => "faucets", :action => "faucet", :method=>:post}%>
```

my link at application.html.erb

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <%= link_to "faucet", faucets_path, class:"nav-link" %>
</li>
```

## Oh and my error

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Faucets#index
Showing /home/floup/Bureau/_THP/35_projet_final/Nepalis_city/app/views/faucets/index.html.erb where line #4 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"faucet", :controller=>"faucets", :method=>:post}
Extracted source (around line #4):
2
3
4
              
<p class="d-flex justify-content-center p-3">Wallet : <%= current_user.wallet  %></p>

<%= button_to 'faucet', {:controller => "faucets", :action => "faucet", :method=>:post}%>

Rails.root: /home/floup/Bureau/_THP/35_projet_final/Nepalis_city

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/faucets/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_faucets_index_html_erb___3525983667023434407_19860'
Request
Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response
Headers:

None
x
>>
```

Comment: Changing this `resources :faucets` to `resources :faucets, only: [:show,:index] { post 'faucet', on: :collection}` should work

Comment: thanks !

i do this ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `faucet` method as a collection to the `faucets` resource:

```rb
# routes.rb
  resources :faucets do
    collection do
      post :faucet
    end
  end
```

With this in place your button will work, but you have to adjust the `link_to` to `faucet_faucets_path`.

Comment: Oh ok thanks ;)

I test this !

but id not possible too do that without post (maybe is supid but i am beginner^^)

Comment: Yes you can also do a get instead of post.

Comment: no i want to if it is possible do create a new route without get or post 

i see it is possible with patch

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use this:

```
resources :faucets do
    collection do
      patch :faucet
    end
  end
```